# Rendering JSOn in controller gives my strange errors

Tags: json, grails

I render a return JSON value in my controller:

```
 def index = {

        def g_resourcen = []
        def g_standorte = []


    def query = "from Resource as b where b.typ='MDLT' and b.varchar_1 <> '' order by b.name"

        Resource.findAll(query).each{


                g_standorte << [id:it.id, name:it.name, standorte: it.standorte]
                g_resourcen << [id:it.id, name:it.name, gruppe: it.resourcenGruppe]
            }

        println("1: ");
        println(g_resourcen);

        println("2: ")
        println(g_standorte);


        [  g_resourcen: g_resourcen as JSON, 
         g_standorte: g_standorte as JSON
     ]


    }
```

And retrieved it on the client side like this:

```
 var g_standorte = dojo.fromJson('${g_standorte}');
```

The g_resourcen works fine but the g_standort gives errors. I have multiple situation in my code exactly like this one which work. But here I keep getting this strange error:

```
Error 500: Error processing GroovyPageView: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.exceptions.ConverterException: Error converting Bean with class sun.proxy.$Proxy15
Servlet: grails
URI: /etermin/grails/terminKorridor/index.dispatch
Exception Message: No signature of method: com.digithurst.global.utils.db.PostgresUtilities$_integerToSqlArray_closure17.doCall() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions: doCall(long, int, java.util.Map), call(), call([Ljava.lang.Object;), call(java.lang.Object), call(long, int, java.util.Map), equals(java.lang.Object) 
Caused by: Error processing GroovyPageView: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.exceptions.ConverterException: Error converting Bean with class sun.proxy.$Proxy15 
Class: /WEB-INF/grails-app/views/terminKorridor/index.gsp 
At Line: [-1] 
Code Snippet:
```

Comment: What I see is you are just sending a `Map` and not a `JSON`. render `as JSON`

Comment: It's done that way: g_standorte: g_standorte as JSON

Comment: [`dojo.fromJson`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/fromJson.html) takes a JSON string. Can you try with a `toString()` on the JSON object?

Comment: What does the `Resource` domain look like? Are you exporting all the attributes of the domain? It would also be helpful to see the entire controller method or at least the return statement.

Comment: No I am exporting the attributes specified in the query, I've updated the question with the whoile method

Comment: The controller action looks ok, and looking closer at the exception, it appears the error is in your index.gsp.

Comment: I was able to find a sollution by rendering only the properties that I wanted like this:standorte:r.standorte.collect {p-> [name:p.name, id:p.id ]}